# How to effectively replicate ArrayList.BinarySearch in List<T>.BinarySearch?

Tags: c#, generics, arraylist, binary-search

I am trying to upgrade an old project from using ArrayList collections to List.  Everything went pretty smooth, except for converting ArrayList.BinarySearch.  While List has a corresponding method, the ArrayList.BinarySearch has an overload that accepts an [arbitrary object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4y1ah87%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) while List.BinarySearch demands an [object of type T](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  Example below.

How can I effectively replace this ArrayList functionality with List?  Or do I have to roll my own?

```
class Pod {
   public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}

class TimeRange: IComparer {
    TimeSpan StartsAt { get; set; }
    ITimeRangeComparer TimeComparer { get; set; }
    public int Compare(object x, object y) {
       // there is more to it, but basically compares time ranges
       return comparer.Compare((TimeRange) x, (TimeRange) y);
    }        
}

class Manager {
   void DoStuff() {
        ArrayList alPods = GetPodsAL();
        List<Pod> lstPods = GetPodsLST();
        int stopIndex;

        TimeRange startPoint = GetStartPoint();
        TimeRange stopPoint = GetStopPoint();

        // ArrayList works fine
        stopIndex = alPods.BinarySearch(stopPoint, startPoint.TimeComparer);

        // Fails because the method demands that `stopPoint` be of type Pod
        stopIndex = lstPods.BinarySearch(stopPoint, startPoint.TimeComparer);
   }
}
```

Comment: If you have a `List<T>`, why would you want to pass in an object that isn't of type `T`? Such an object could not be in the list.

Comment: Just write your own BinarySearch extension method for List<T> that would accept arbitrary objects, that should be easy.

Comment: @Dmitry Osinovskiy has an OK idea (make an extention). Personnally I try to avoid extention methods. I think that you should invest more time into refactoring your code and use BinarySearch with the generic Comparer.

Comment: @AdamRobinson You can pass it in if the Comparer object supports it.  The search is based on parameters other than what is in the object.  The code isn't the easiest to understand and was written by a guy that loved abstracting the living crap out of everything to the point that no one could actually understand what was going on.  Thus a foreign object is being passed into the BinarySearch method.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy Can you provide an example of how you would go about it?

Comment: @AngryHacker just take the code from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Search/Binary_search#C.23_.28common_Algorithm.29 and change int[] to List<T>, int to object, add IComparer as a separate parameter, change == and < to a call to comparer. Or take dotPeek/ReSharper and disassembly an ArrayList.BinarySearch.

Comment: I think what you want is a version of BinarySearch that takes a `Func<T, int>`. This is the most general version of binary search and the framework does not provide it :(

Answer (score 1):

To use the same method that `ArrayList.BinarySearch` uses, convert your `List<T>` to an array and call `Array.BinarySearch(Array, object)`. Unfortunately you would need to do a conversion/copy to a new array.

```
List<SomeType> list;
SomeType value;
// ...
Array.BinarySearch(list.ToArray(), value)
```

I do question your approach though, being as a `List<T>` is strongly-typed, it will only ever contain the type `T`. If you're unsure for some reason whether the type would be of that in the list then check before-hand or make an extension method to do it for you.

```
public static class ListExtensionMethods
{
    public static int BinarySearch<T>(this List<T> list, object value)
    {
        if (value is T)
            return list.BinarySearch((T)value);
        return -1;
    }
}
```